# how to make program read stopwatch and then print statement in another textview box when time reaches that second

Tags: java, android, if-statement, timer

I want to make a stopwatch. when my stopwatch reaches 1 minute I want it to print a statement, how can i make it do this?

I am using android studio(java), Here is a bit of my code:

```
Button btnStart,btnPause,btnLap;
TextView txtTimer;
Handler customHandler = new Handler();
LinearLayout container;
TextView lt;

 long startTime=0L,timeinMilliseconds=0L,timeSwapBuff=0L,updateTime=0L;

Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeinMilliseconds =  SystemClock.uptimeMillis() -startTime;
        updateTime = timeSwapBuff+timeinMilliseconds;
        int secs=(int) (updateTime/1000);
        int mins=secs/60;
        secs%=60;
        int milliseconds=(int) (updateTime%1000);
        String s = "" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d",secs) + ":" + String.format("%03d",milliseconds);
        txtTimer.setText (s);
        customHandler.postDelayed(this,0);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to setText after some X minutes just create a method like this:

```
private void printText(int minutes) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do you setText here
        }
    }, minutes * 1000);
}
```

and use it like:

```
printText(1);
```

Update:

[Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) is exactly what you are looking for.

It extends `TextView`, so just replace your timer textview with `Chronometer`

```
 mChronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer2);
 mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
 mChronometer.start();
 mChronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();
        int secs = (int) (elapsedMillis/1000);
        int mins = secs/60;
        if (mins == 1) {
            mChronometer.stop();
            anotherTextVeiw.setText("the 1 minute mark has passed");
        }
    }
});
```

You don't have to deal with `Handler` and `Runnable` with this approach

Comment: i want to print it on another new textview box

Comment: @TaimurShaikh What do you mean by print? Do do mean changing text of the `TextView`? You can set the `TextView` by `txtTimer.setText(myText);` If you want to create new `TextView`, then you need to do create programatically and add it to your view

Comment: there are 2 textview boxes, one is my stopwatch the other is just a blank box, when my stopwatch reaches lets say 1 min i want the other textview box to print a statement e.g. when my stopwatch reaches 1 min i want the other textview to say, "the 1 minute mark has passed"